# Scrapy cannot be installed on windows10 with conda install

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, windows-10, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda (python 3.5) and I wanted to install scrapy but I don't know why it's not working

Input commands:

```
D:\Anaconda\Scripts>conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy
D:\Anaconda\Scripts>conda install scrapy
D:\Anaconda\Scripts>conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda scrapy
```

Output:

```
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - cffi (target=cffi-1.5.2-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - conda -> conda-env
  - conda -> menuinst
  - conda -> pycosat
  - conda -> python 2.7*
  - conda -> pyyaml
  - conda -> requests
  - conda-env (target=conda-env-2.4.5-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> cffi
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> idna 2.0|2.1
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> openssl 1.0.2g
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> pyasn1 0.1.7|0.1.8|0.1.9
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|
3.5*
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> setuptools
  - cryptography (target=cryptography-1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> six
  - idna (target=idna-2.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - lxml (target=lxml-3.6.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*
  - menuinst (target=menuinst-1.3.2-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - nose (target=nose-1.3.7-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*
  - pip (target=pip-8.1.1-py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*
  - pip (target=pip-8.1.1-py35_1.tar.bz2) -> wheel
  - pyasn1 (target=pyasn1-0.1.9-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pycosat (target=pycosat-0.6.1-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pycparser (target=pycparser-2.14-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pyopenssl (target=pyopenssl-0.15.1-py35_2.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5
*
  - python 3.5*
  - pyyaml (target=pyyaml-3.11-py35_3.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*
  - requests (target=requests-2.9.1-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - scrapy -> lxml
  - scrapy -> pyopenssl 0.14|0.15.1
  - scrapy -> python 2.6*|2.7*
  - scrapy -> setuptools
  - scrapy -> six
  - setuptools (target=setuptools-20.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5
*
  - six (target=six-1.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - wheel (target=wheel-0.29.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Please let me know what can I do to install scrapy with py3.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem use below code(I have download a whl file to Scripts dir in scrapy web[Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.py3-none-any.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/c4/33/a87d324a3c25b6e6e8018b9161987e185910bd6e611ebb75ce169a7f1312/Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=938197576678c365475e242f27dfa24e)):

```
D:\Anaconda\Scripts>pip install Scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: I use your code but hava a error`Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels:- scrapy 1.1.0rc3*` Is that means scrapy don't support win10-64bit?

Comment: My bad. can you try `conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy=1.1.0rc3`? i.e. specifying the "scrapinghub" channel

Comment: I try it but the error same like above(remove 1.1.0rc3 itswork).BTW,i can't use scrapy in my anaconda4.0-64bit-py3.5. Is that twisted not support 64bit so scrapy can't run?

Comment: According to [this page](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/twisted), Twisted is available for Anaconda win 64bit. I have not tested the combination myself though.

Comment: I see that but my Scrapy still not working.Scrapy py3.5 not good :(

Comment: with same error? what do you mean by "Scrapy py3.5 not good" ?